# Is it possible to make the iPhone keyboard invisible / remove it without resigning first responder?

Tags: iphone, uikit, keyboard, uitextview

I am looking for a way to show my own input view (a UITableView) to enter certain keywords in a UITextView faster than typing them, and also be able to type into this text view the normal way. My solution has a button that causes the keyboard to disappear, revealing the table view underneath it.

Problem is I can't figure out how to make the keyboard go away without resigning first responder, and losing the cursor. Has anyone accomplished this before?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope

As far as I know there is no way to do this, and I have searched extensively. Very frustrating that selection and the cursor are restricted to the keyboard.

I could be wrong though. Votes? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `becomeFirstResponder` on some other thing that you choose. It could be a `UIViewController` or a `UIView`. I had a similar problem before, I needed to make my keyboard go away when I was pushing my view controller back to its caller, without knowing which textfield was the first responder. Then, on viewWillAppear of my view controller which I was returning back, I called `[self becomeFirstResponder]` and the keyboard of the pushed view was gone. Because this made whichever text field was it loose being the first responder.

Comment: That does make the keyboard go away without resigning first responder, but it doesn't allow me to keep the cursor in the text view so I can add things in using my own input view.